# Meaning of 'give some point' and 'protracted description'

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the sentence that I don't know the meaning exactly. 
I know the meaning of 'give point', which means like 'accent' and 
I know the meaning of both 'protracted' and 'description' but I can't translate
both together.

*It does not seem an unreasonable expectation that something will follow which will **give some point** to this rather **protracted description** of Simon Lee.*

Answer (score 4):

The **protracted description** is a **long** and **verbose** explanation of Simon Lee, which could be **TL;DR** in internet shorthand.

In your passage, to **give some point to** means to **give a reason to**.

> I can see your **point**

The reader is expecting **a good point** to be made after enduring such a lengthy description, otherwise it all would have been **pointless**.

Comment: @Peter- You nailed the answer. As an aside, what does **TL;DR** mean? This is the second time I've seen it.

Comment: **T** oo **L** ong **;D** on't **R** ead  can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read)